# Can't create entities from database

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I have an existing MySql database and I'm trying to extract the entities.
I'm using a symfony project but I'm new to the whole symfony thing.
I've tried `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml` like it says on their website but I'm getting an error:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/wsgpKmw.jpg]

Can anyone help me out?
thanks!

Comment: Use AppBundle instead of AcmeBlogBundle.  There is a note in the docs which states: "In this tutorial it's assumed that an AcmeBlogBundle exists and is located under the src/Acme/BlogBundle folder." Clearly you have not done that which is fine.  Or create a blog bundle with bin/console generate:bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `AcmeBlogBundle` in your `AppKernel`

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
                [...] //other bundles
                new Acme\BlogBundle\AcmeBlogBundle(),
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that `AcmeBundle`(s) are test ones, so if you need to develop your custom solution, is better to create your own bundle

Comment: It can't find it: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error: Class 'Acme\BlogBundle\AcmeBlogBundle' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/vrijwilligersproject/app/AppKernel.php on line 19

Comment: @JelleCriel maybe you haven't created it yet? You should have a folder structure like: `src\Acme\BlogBundle` and inside it a file named `AcmeBlogBundle.php` that should be like [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/bundles.html#creating-a-bundle)

Comment: Then how come I have to create my own bundle to generate entities from my database when symfony/doctrine claims to be able to do this for me in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html ?

Comment: @JelleCriel: never said you need to create your own bundle TO generate entities, but that you need to create a bundle (different from Acme one) just because, for convention, them are used as applications examples. If you want to generate them into AcmeBlogBundle you can, of course, but without more details, I can't safely say if this is the right choice

Comment: I'll take a fresh look at it tommorow morning, thanks!

Comment: So, I did take another fresh look at it. I'm now using the default AppBundle (just trying to make things work) and I'm getting the following error:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/rAE5hQf.jpg)
thing is I'm 99% sure it is only declared once!

Comment: Ok, I figured out that visual paradigm created some duplicate foreign keys. I removed it and now it works. yeey!

Answer (score 1):

As written in the documentation, you have to enable the bundle: just edit the AppKernel.php:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
// ...

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        );

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: These are my bundles:
`$bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        ];
`
How do I know which one to add?`